# Is it possible to use Jasmine tests written for UI with Jmeter for load testing?

Tags: jmeter, protractor

We have a lot of UI automation scripts written in typescript and we use Protractor with Jasmine test framework to run them. They work great and now we want to do load testing with jMeter. Is it possible to hook up these UI tests in jMeter instead of recording the same flows again separately? I have read that Loadrunner allowed using winrunner scripts from the UI automation. I wanted to do something similar with my UI tests and jMeter. Is it feasible?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Regards,
Vikas

Comment: LoadRunner still allows a GUI virtual user.  At the current time this is implemented with QuickTest Professional.  WinRunner has not been an option for quite a few years

Comment: Thanks James for your comment. I have not used either of the tool so I was not aware of it. :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of months ago I tried to do exactly that but couldn't find way to do it.

I ended up writing my tests with jMeter + Selenium and using [BlazeMeter](https://blazemeter.com/) to run them. Not the most exciting work I had to do. The good thing about BlazeMeter is that they have a nice chrome extension that lets you record the test and directly deploy it to your tests database that is accessible through your dashboard.

Comment: Thanks @nebermudezs for sharing your solution. Is your application an angularJs application? Due to limitations of selenium as is we are using protractor (built on top of webdriverjs). I will do a small POC with your set up suggestion. But what I am hearing is that I cannot re-use the ui automations scripts with jmeter.

Comment: It is a NodeJs + ReactJs application, and it uses Protractor + Jasmine for E2E and unit tests. Some of the tests did end up with ugly `sleep`s to make them work. My app was rather simple, a WebRTC app for video calls + chat, which didn't require super complex selenium tests. We were also against the clock, the other option we explored was to create a docker container farm in Amazon, each machine would start your script that runs the protractor tests, setup NewRelic in the app and monitor it that way. It is theoretically possible and maybe worth a try.

Comment: Thanks nebermudezs for sharing your experiences and suggestions. It is really helpful. I will see what fits our project's need. :)